# Observables Basics

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I believe I have a use case which is appropriate for Observables but I'm not sure how to implement as Observables are not the most intuitive concept.
Lets say I have 3 numbers: `let a: number, b: number, c: number;` and I want to monitor them as they change. `if((a + b + c) / 3 === 0)) return true else false`. How can I create an observer  that will monitor those numbers and using it I can get the `boolean` value?

Comment: Who are these monsters who downvote without even a comment?

Comment: You define 4 streams (observables): 1 for each individual variable and 1 that combines their values into that expression. If you want to learn by yourself check https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: how is this related to angular?

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous for a sad reason. Many usually helpful people have had bad experiences with people starting a war of downvoting, flaming etc. Commenting on the reason for a downvote is appreciated, but the policy is not to require it.

Comment: Possible reasons for down voting: a meaningless title that doesn't summarize the question; not having shown any effort to solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. In real life `aSubject`, `bSubject`, and `cSubject` are regular `Observable` streams that you either construct, or get from your framework or choice, etc.

In my demo, I use `BehaviorSubject`s, because technically speaking, `Subjects` *are* `Observables`.

The *Setup* part of the code creates the three source streams, and the `formulaObservable` that checks whether the sum of the last known values of `a`, `b`, `c`, divided by `3` is `0`. Notice that `aSubject.next(1)` is somewhat similar in a sense to `a = 1` in "normal" JS. The key difference is that `.next()` is creating an *even* in the Observable stream.

The `combineLatest()` operator creates a new Observable that looks at *n* input Observable streams and calculates some function of last known values of those n streams.

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

// "Setup"

const aSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | undefined>(undefined);
const bSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | undefined>(undefined);
const cSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | undefined>(undefined);

const formulaObservable = Observable
  .combineLatest(
    aSubject,
    bSubject,
    cSubject,
  )
  .map(values => {
    const [a, b, c] = values;
    if (a == null || b == null || c == null) {
      return Observable.never();
    } else {
      return (a + b + c) / 3 === 0;
    }
  });

formulaObservable.subscribe(result => console.warn(`Result: ${result}`));

// ---
// "Usage"

aSubject.next(1);
bSubject.next(2);
cSubject.next(1); // a===1, b===2,         c===1,         formulaObservable==Observable.of(false)
bSubject.next(1); // a===1, b===1,         c===1,         formulaObservable==Observable.of(true)
```

Hope, it helps.

---

P.S. You can play with the interactive [RxJsMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) to understand how they work better. Notice that the colored balls are draggable.

P.P.S. This is an okay question, but I think your downvotes are coming from either the fact you didn't do the research (no code posted along the question itself), or because you didn't search on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Zachscs yeah, np

Comment: You are constructing a somewhat weird stream here because the resulting type is `Observable<boolean | Observable<any>>`. If you don't want to emit on null inputs, you should `filter` them.

Comment: That's a good point, essentially break `map` up into a `filter` then `map`, simplifying considerably.

Comment: Good answer though!

Comment: There are many way to achieve what OP is asking, I'm just showing _a_ way. And yes, I'll polish the details when I get time.

Comment: What's much more important is the fact this question got -3 in votes even though it's a valid question. When one is new to observables, you don't know where to start.

Comment: There's an argument for bit-shifting the voting system: don't like it = don't vote (no down vote), one vote = question is well presented (2pts), two votes = question is novel and informative (+8pts).